# Zend > Mail > setFrom() doesn't do anything

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend Mail as follows:

```
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($smtpSettings['smtpServer'], $smtpSettings);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();

.
.
.
$mail->setFrom("support@somedomain.com", "Support");
.
.
.

$mail->send($transport);
```

I am successfully receiving the e-mail. But in place of the sender e-mail, instead of "support@somedomain.com", I am getting the G-Mail address (that I used up for SMTP configuration).

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that GMail SMTP server doesn't allow to send emails from @somedomain.com. You should use SMTP server installed on somedomain.com

Comment: I think you are right: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370

Answer (score 1):

**Set** 
$mailInstance->clearDefaultFrom();
**before**
$mailInstance->setFrom($params['from'], $params['fromName']);